# how to assign an empty value to a variable via loop in batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

as you can see below i trying to assign the first and last "empty non IP" values to a variable using for /f loop.

for some reason the loop is not parsing the empty IP values and picking only the middle one

```
C:\Windows\System32>ipconfig | find "Default"
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.188.2
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

that's my code...thanks a lot !!

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=0
    ipconfig | find "Default Gateway" > %temp%\TEMPIP.txt
    for /f "tokens=12 delims=: " %%a in (%temp%\TEMPIP.txt) do (


    set /a count+=1
    echo %%a > %temp%\TEMP.txt
    set gw=%%a
    set gwvar!count!=!gw!

 )

    echo now...
    echo.
    echo var1 is... %gwvar1%
    echo var2 is... %gwvar2%

    pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.188.2
^       ^       ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^   ^
1       2       3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 11  12
```

Your code is asking for token number 12. The only line that has 12 tokens is the one with a ip address, so, the code in the `do` clause is not executed for the other two lines as there is no token to process.

You can use

```
set "count=0"
for /f "tokens=11,* delims=: " %%a in ('
    ipconfig ^| find "Default"
') do (
    set /a "count+=1"
    set "gwvar!count!=%%b"
)

set gwvar
```

`%%b` (`*` the rest after the 11th token) is used as `%%a` will hold the last dot (the 11th token)

Comment: works like a charm! so for all...this is the working solution

Answer (score 0):

Interesting observation - but not quite accurate.

set count=

will set ERRORLEVEL to 1 IF var undefined, but leave ERRORLEVEL unchanged if 
var is defined
whereas set count=something else will leave ERRORLEVEL unchanged regardless 
(empirically determined)

if defined count set  count=

would appear to stop the problem you appear to be encountering.